# CodeIgniter template problem

Tags: templates, class, codeigniter, github

Hello all CodeIgniter guys :), I'm new to CodeIgniter andIi have now put my project on github. Here is my github page: https://github.com/SimonJ/Hip-hop-project

So I would hear about someone bothered to look through my files and make comments about what I can do better so I can learn something new :)

I have tried to use ocular template system but I get this error:

> An Error Was Encounter Unable to load the Requested Class: ocular

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question borders on the edge of belonging on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of Stack Overflow, but I'll help you with your templating issue.

1. Are you running PHP 5 on your server? It looks like Ocular is using "public" and "private" words for functions and variables.
2. You are running an older version of Codeigniter by the looks of it because I don't see a folder called "core" in your application folder. There's a community version of CI called Reactor [here](https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter-reactor/) or you can get the standard CI 2.0 from EllisLab [here](http://codeigniter.com/downloads/). I would upgrade to one of those, personally I would use Reactor.
3. Ocular is great but Phil Sturgeon has a lighter template library simply called template you might be interested in looking at as well, [here](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code/codeigniter-template). Like I said in the first paragraph of this answer, go to Code Review if you would like to have your code critiqued and reviewed.

PS. Welcome to Codeigniter, it's an awesome PHP framework.

Comment: im running PHP Version 5.3.2. ocular have a nice codeigniter flash system i want to use to echo out error message and like that :), so i will try to get it to work, i have now put the new version of codeigniter up and get this error now: 
Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ci/application/controllers/forside.php on line 3
dont know what the problem is :(

Comment: CI 2.0 uses the base controller class `CI_Controller`, not `Controller`

Comment: Yep. Models now extend CI_Model instead of Model and controllers now extend CI_Controller instead of Controller. I probably should have mentioned that before telling you to upgrade, I apologise for that.